# Custom child view bringToFront not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

I have a custom view added as a child of a LinearLayout. I need this custom view to anchor to the bottom irrespective of the parent viewgroup. Here's how I'm doing it.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (!drawn) {
        drawn = true;
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        ((View) getParent()).getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
        setY(rect.bottom - rect.top - getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.bottom_bar_height));

        setZ(UiUtils.dpToPx(8f));
        forceLayout();
        bringToFront();
    } else {
        binding.bottomBarLl.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

When I add the custom view to a LinearLayout parent, if the children above this child have match_parent height, this one doesn't show.

Below is a screenshot from the layout inspector where it is shown to be laid out but doesn't show.

[image]

The inspector also shows that the getZ() of the custom view is 24.

I'm building for API level 21+ but I've also tried `((View) getParent()).invalidate();` and `getParent().requestLayout();` in the onDraw() to no good.

From the documentation for [View.bringToFront()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront())

> bringToFront
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> void bringToFront ()
>
> Change the view's z order in
>   the tree, so it's on top of other sibling views. This ordering change
>   may affect layout, if the parent container uses an order-dependent
>   layout scheme (e.g., LinearLayout). Prior to KITKAT this method should
>   be followed by calls to requestLayout() and invalidate() on the view's
>   parent to force the parent to redraw with the new child ordering.

this should be working, but it isn't for me. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Like other questions which couldn't get it to work with a LinearLayout, I also used a coordinator layout finally where the linear layout and my custom view are siblings and things are working fine. It would be great if someone could explain the documentation though, since it is misleading otherwise.